# PDFSharp compress filesize in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

In my App i generate an PDF-File with PDFSharp.Xamarin which I got from this site:
https://github.com/roceh/PdfSharp.Xamarin

Everything is working fine.
In my PDF-Document I have many Images, which are compressed.
But the file size of my PDF-Document is too large.

Is there a possibility to compress my PDF-Document before saving it?

How can I work with the PdfSharp.SharpZipLib.Zip Namespace to deflate the file size?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my Code:

```
document = new PdfDocument();
document.Info.Title = nameDok.Replace(" ", "");
document.Info.Author = "---";
document.Info.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
document.Info.Subject = nameDok.Replace(" ", "");

//That is how i add Images:
XImage image = XImage.FromStream(lstr);
gfx.DrawImage(image, 465, YPrev - 2, newimagewf, newimagehf);

document.CustomValues.CompressionMode = PdfCustomValueCompressionMode.Compressed;
document.Options.FlateEncodeMode = PdfFlateEncodeMode.BestCompression;

document.Save(speicherPfad);
```

Thanks for everyone.

Comment: Can you shared your code?

Comment: I edit my question with the Code

Comment: Would you share some PDFs? Maybe one PDF with one image each for all image formats you are using (e.g. JPEG, PNG, GIF, ...).

Comment: I use jpeg Images which i compress before adding to the pdf

Comment: JPEG images should be copied into the PDF file. If they are converted to bitmaps then size may increase quite a bit. I can tell that from the PDF. Is it still JPEG in the PDF file? Look for "/Filter/DCTDecode" in the PDF.

Comment: Just a note: deflating an already deflated file can result in a larger file. The second deflate has to add its header and symbol tree and the likelihood of getting any further compression is slim.

Answer (score 2):

I only know the original PDFsharp, not the Xamarin port: images are deflated automatically using SharpZipLib.

Make sure to use appropriate source images (e.g. JPEG or PNG, depending on the image).

On the project start page they write:
"Currently all images created via XGraphics are converted to jpegs with 70% quality."
This could mean that images are re-compressed, maybe leading to larger files than before.
Take one JPEG file, convert it to PDF, and check the size of the image (in bytes) in the PDF file.

Comment: Yes, but I think there is a way to compress the complete PDF-File with SharpZipLib

Comment: Each image will be compressed separately, but not the whole file.